# Python - How to merge/concat Dataset when index has only 1 value

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I'm quite new with the XArray library and I have difficulties with a the concat/merge functions.

So I have several Datasets with this kind of coordinates

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (latitude: 721, longitude: 1440)
Coordinates:
    number         int64 0
    time           datetime64[ns] 2019-09-01
    step           timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00
    isobaricInhPa  int64 1000
  * latitude       (latitude) float64 90.0 89.75 89.5 ... -89.5 -89.75 -90.0
  * longitude      (longitude) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 359.2 359.5 359.8
    valid_time     datetime64[ns] 2019-09-01
Data variables:
    t              (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
```

Each describes the atmospheric temperature for a different pressure level (`isobaricInhPa`) and a date (`time`) different. I would like to merge then in a unique dataset. For instance, I keep only the ones describing for a unique pressure level but at different dates.
I collect the different Dataset matching dates and pressures from grib files and merge then using their `latitude`, `longitude`, `isobaricInhPa` and `time`.

To do so, I tried to turn `time` and `isobaricInhPa` to dimensions. But, since they have only 1 value, `numpy.ndarray` decide it's a 0-d array. In other situations, I would use `np.atleast_1d(time)` or `np.atleast_1d(isobaricInhPa)`. In this case, the following code does not work.

```py
ds = ds.set_index({entry: entry})
```

I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
DatetimeIndex() must be called with a collection of some kind, numpy.datetime64('2019-11-01T00:00:00.000000000') was passed
```

How to merge then in this case ? How to avoid overwriting data because the library use only `latitude` and `longitude` and not `time` and `isobaricInhPa` ?